# Create js sprite freezing on first frame

Tags: createjs

Pulling my hair out with this one, hope its not something silly. Below is a snippet of code from a program. When `leftwalker.x == 150` he should `gotoAndPlay` the standstill animation but it only plays the first frame, the previous animation runs fine. Any ideas?

```
var data = 
         {
         images: ["images/ste_basic_wand.png"],
         frames: {width:64, height:64},
         animations: 
            {
                // start, end, next, speed
                walkright: [143,151,"walkright",1.18],
                walkleft: [118,125,"walkleft",1.18],
                stand:[39,45,"stand",0.08],
                standstill:[26,27, "standstill", 1.2]
            }

         };
         var spriteSheet = new createjs.SpriteSheet(data);

         leftwalker = new createjs.Sprite(spriteSheet);
         leftwalker.name = "lefty";
         leftwalker.framerate = 30;
         leftwalker.x = 100;
         leftwalker.y = 100;
         leftwalker.currentFrame = 0;
         leftwalker.scaleY = leftwalker.scaleX = 2;

         leftwalker.gotoAndPlay("walkright");

         stage.addChild(leftwalker);
         createjs.Ticker.setFPS(10);    
         createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", tick);    
    }

    function tick(event) {
        if(container.x < 150)
        {   
        container.x += 5;
        }
        if(leftwalker.x < 150)
        {
            leftwalker.x += 2;
        }
        if(leftwalker.x == 150)
        {
            leftwalker.gotoAndPlay("standstill");
        }
        //  if (circle.x > stage.canvas.width) { circle.x = 0; }
        stage.update(event); // important!!
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this happens is because you are calling `gotoAndPlay("standstill")` during the tick. Once you reach 150, your sprite stops moving, so it is perpetually at `x=150`. This means each tick will tell it to `gotoAndPlay` the same frame, resulting it in being "stuck".

Comment: Hi Lanny, thanks for the tip, I think I understand the issue now. What is standard practice in createjs for changing the animation in such cases so it won't be stuck? I've tried calling it from external functions but the result is the same.

Comment: You could look up the `currentAnimation` on the Sprite. If it is not "standstill", then tell it to gotoAndPlay that animation.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a way around it, still not sure why but easaljs didn't like the code

```
if(leftwalker.x == 150)
        {
            leftwalker.gotoAndPlay("standstill");
        }
```

When I change it so the char isn't stuck on point 150 (move him to 151) the animation begins. I also slowed the animation on the standing still down to make it seem more real but this isn't related to the fix I didn't post this code.

```
if(leftwalker.x == 150)
        {
            leftwalker.gotoAndPlay("standstill");
            if(leftwalker.x < 180)
            {
                leftwalker.x += 1;
            }
        }
```